# Image doesn't load in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm having trouble uploading an image in pygame. Here's my code.

```
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *

def Capitals():

    pygame.init()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Capitals')
    BLACK = (  0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255) 
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    DISPLAYSURF=pygame.image.load('USA.jpg').convert()
    while True:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type==QUIT:
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit()
      pygame.display.update()
```

The picture isn't having a problem loading on the python page, there is no "cannot open file error", but on the actual pygame window, the image isn't loading.

Answer (score 2):

To display an image on the screen, you have to draw it on the display surface (using [`blit`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)). What you are doing here

```
DISPLAYSURF=pygame.image.load('USA.jpg').convert()
```

is loading the image and assign it to the `DISPLAYSURF` variable.

So use this instead:

```
image=pygame.image.load('USA.jpg').convert() # load the image
DISPLAYSURF.blit(image, (0, 0)) # blit it to the screen
```